# Thermodynamics cooling curve question

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm given that a solid is heated, beyond melting point and then the temperature of the liquid is 90 Celsius. When it cools, the temp falls to around 80 Celsius and stays constant for a period of minutes before falling again.

What would 80 Celsius represent here in thermodynamics terms?

Am I  right in assuming it's the temperature just above the solid - liquid phase change on a cooling curve?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/ocr_gateway/home_energy/heating_housesrev3.shtml

Comment: Thanks, but in this question it mentions that the liquid remains at  a constant temperature of 80 celcius for several minutes after falling from 90, and then falls again?

Comment: I suspect it might be the given liquid re solidifying?

Comment: So the "several minutes" must represent the phase change from liquid - solid right?

Comment: Yes, of course. As the link shows. Pure substances have a definite melting/solidifying point. During melting/solidifying the temperature remains constant, at least for slow cooling/heating.

Comment: Why would the temperature remain constant despite heat still being lost to the surroundings? Is there a law of physics which accounts for this?

Just to help me understand, sorry

Comment: This is due to latent heat, typical for all (?) [first-order phase transitions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80245/first-and-second-order-phase-transitions).

Comment: So are we talking about the reverse of latent heat of fusion?

Comment: And an explanation would just be that latent heat is the energy required, without a change in temp?

Comment: So I understand that latent heat measures the change in internal heat energy, without a change in temp. Why would the temperature remain constant? Because it just does when this change of state is occurring?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_fusion

Comment: And so after the latent heat of fusion stage the temperature can fall again, purely because the substance is totally in the solid stage, correct?

Thanks for all assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in assuming it's the temperature just above the solid - liquid phase change on a cooling curve?

Not *above*, but exactly *at* the solid-to-liquid (or rather liquid-to-solid, also known as *freezing* or *solidification*) phase change region:

[image]

Considering water, it might start at $10 \;\mathrm{^\circ C}$ and is then cooled down to $-10 \;\mathrm{^\circ C}$. Along the way, there will be a while of constant-temperature cooling at exactly $0 \;\mathrm{^\circ C}$.